# Distributing scheduled tasks across multi-datacenter environment in Node.js with Cassandra

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, distributed, paxos, raft

We are attempting to build a system that gets a list of task to execute from a Cassandra database and then through some kind of group consensus creates an execution plan (preferably on one node) which is then agreed on and executed by the entire cluster of servers.  We really do not want to add any additional pieces of software such as Redis or a AMPQ system, rather have the consensus built directly into all of the servers running the jobs.  So far we have found Skiff, an implementation of the Raft algorithm that looks like it could accomplish the task, but I was wondering if anyone has found an elegant solution to this problem in a pure Node.js way not involving external messaging systems.

Comment: Using Cassandra's Paxos was the solution as @rystov mentioned below.  As for a cron like scheduling system built on top of Cassandra we created a table in which we input the numerical interval / unit (e.g. min, hour), and a map value that contained the jobs.  `CREATE TABLE bakup.tasks_schd (
    interval int,
    unit text,
    jobs map<text, text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (interval, unit)
);`  We then query based on whether we are on a certain min, hour, day, etc and join the jobs on the application server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra supports lightweight transactions, which is basically Paxos implementation that offers linearizable consistency and CAS operation (consensus). So you can use Cassandra itself to serialize the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that's exactly what I am pursuing!  I am testing it for election of a task coordinator at the moment at it works very well for interval based selection if the servers are all within a few milliseconds of one another.  The trick now is to figure out how to replicate a cron like scheduling mechanism that utilizes Cassandra to store the tasks to be scheduled, allowing the app to query based on the interval for jobs to perform.